# required nullable int

Tags: c#, nullable

I recently started on a new project and came across the following.
I'm looking at a class `Widget` which has a property:

```
[Required]
public int? WidgetTypeId { get; set; }
```

I'm struggling to see how this makes sense; if the field is `Required` why would it be nullable?  (I understand the answer may be "human error".  I'm wondering if there is a *legitimate* reason for doing this.)

Data points:

- I haven't done an exhaustive analysis but the UI (the bits with which I am familiar at any rate) appears to require the field to be populated.
- There is a backing database table, and the database column in question is not nullable.

Comment: Hard to say for your use case but I've certainly seen that when we do not have a reasonable default (0 has meaning or whatever) and want to allow a thing to be null so it can be explicitly set / validated.

Comment: is it bound to any control ?

Comment: Where's the `DateTime`? And, what's the context. Where/how is the field used

Comment: on the answer im guessing you are on MVC and property is DateTime? , hope im correct.

Comment: @PeterSmith my bad, it is in fact an `int`.  The type ID identifies the Widget Type ie it's a foreign key.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator it is an `int` the question body was correct the title was not. it's not MVC, it's an AngularJS UI, but there's a drop-down with the available widget types and the control value gets set to the ID of the selected type.

Comment: indeed it is for the same reason, few edits on the answer thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is prevent under posting hacks. Also it displays an empty value in the view instead of the default value.

If it is non nullable DefaultModelBinder initializes with default value 0(Zero) thus no ModelState error is  generated.

In your case if an attack omits the property on a request a ModelState error is generated.

Model Validation: [Model Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)

***Although the post is about ASP.NET MVC 2, the issues are still relevant to Web API.***
Under Posting Problem: [Under and over posting problems](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html)